# Paginação com JQuery PHP MySql no modelo MVC

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mvc, paginação

Bem estou com um probleminha, tenho uma tabela com as conversas de um chat interno do sistema que foi criado aqui na empresa. Minha tarefa será paginar o histórico gerado com os botões de "Anterior" e "Próximo" limitando o número de mensagens enviadas. Tenho o código do `html`, `javascript` e `php`(controlador) espero que se não conseguirem me ajudar por completo alguma luz já seria suficiente para minha caminhada!

O código em html:

```
<div class="row mtop10" style="height:95% !important; margin-bottom: -30px;">
   <div class="col-xs-12 historico_chat" id="historico_chat">

   </div>
</div>
<center>
    <button id="anterior" class="anterior">&lt;&lt; Anterior</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span id="numeracao"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button id="proximo" class="proximo">Próximo &gt;&gt;</button>
</center>
```

O código em PHP:

```
public function ajaxcarregaHistoricochat(){

 $obj_chat        = new daoChat();
 $chat            = $obj_chat->Where(" (iat_destinatario = '".$_POST['ifu']."' AND iat_remetente = '".$_POST['remetente']."') OR (iat_destinatario = '".$_POST['remetente']."' AND iat_remetente = '".$_POST['ifu']."') ")->Limite(1, 10)->Recursiva()->Consultar();

 $html  ="";
 $html .="<div>";
      foreach ($chat as $ch){
          $html .="<p style='color: blue; font-weight: bold; text-align:left;'>".$ch['iat_destinatario']."</p>";
          $html .="<p style='color: red;text-align:left;'>".$ch['iat_mensagem']."</p>";
      }

    $html .="</div>";

    echo $html;
}
```

E o código em JS:

```
$("body").on("click",".abre_historico",function(){
    $(".modal_historico").css("z-index","999");
    modal.style.display = "block";
    var remetente = $("#chat_remetente").val();
    var ifu       = $(this).data("ifu");
    //alert(ifu);
    $.post(""+url+"insoft/header/ajaxcarregaHistoricochat",{remetente:remetente,ifu:ifu},function(data){
        $("#historico_chat").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Obrigado @KennyRafael :D

Comment: Acabei esquecendo mas "#chat_remetente" é onde recebe o valor do remetente da conversa , "abre_historico" é o botão que faz a abertura do modal box onde é carregado o historico e "var ifu       = $(this).data("ifu");" é a variável que recebe o valor do data-ifu que seria o destinatario através do controlador no php.

Comment: Eu consigo carregar as mensagens pertinentes ao remetente logado e seu destinatario e limita-las atraves da função limite vista no codigo do php acima, mas o restante nao consigo carregar.

Comment: Qual seria a dificuldade que você está enfrentando?